# Auction site on Node.js, how do i schedule an event/trigger an event automatically?

Tags: node.js, events, triggers, auto

Hello I am developing an auction site and I have figured out all the logic on getting a server time, and comparing that to an auction end date.

Now my question is how do I trigger an event on Node?

Is this a job for cron jobs?
How do I set cron jobs automatically from node? if yes.

Auctions are made by users. I have this part working.

Would an event that is created disappear with cron(or whatever solution) if the server restarts (which happens with node a lot like when editing and updated pages)

I would like to schedule an event to happen based on when the users wants the auction to end.

I feel it would be inefficient and costly(for performance) to always scan the mysql, calculate end dates and check every minute or so. Plus i want it to be organic feeling like when the auction ends the seller gets an email( i have this solved too)

Any help would be great! Thank you!!